# PreferenceFragment on pre-ICS

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

How do I use PreferenceFragment on older Android versions? ActionBarSherlock and Google's compatibility library doesn't seem to have an alternative implementation.
Will it work correctly if I make an ActivityGroup and add a PreferenceActivity into it as a simple fragment?
Targeting only ICS and newer would solve all problems, but, unfortunately, 2.3.x does have a half of whole market.

Comment: I would recommend check this library https://github.com/saik0/UnifiedPreference
<br>It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I use PreferenceFragment on older Android versions?

You don't. As you note, there is no backport, and backporting it would be rather challenging (as I researched this once upon a time and ran away screaming).

> Will it work correctly if I make an ActivityGroup and add a PreferenceActivity into it as a simple fragment?

I wouldn't do that. I would create a `PreferenceActivity` that uses `PreferenceFragment` on newer devices and just uses ordinary preference XML on older devices. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Prefs/FragmentsBC) that demonstrates this.

Comment: @Grishka: Personally, I do not think that's a good UI model. You are welcome to create a UI that looks like preferences out of regular views. `ActivityGroup` has been deprecated for nearly two years.

Comment: ActivityGroup is deprecated only since Honeycomb, isn't it?

Comment: @Grishka: Correct, though that has been out for nearly two years. Time flies when you're having fun. :-)

Comment: but pre-honeycomb doesn't know that it's deprecated :)
And it's the only way to open an activity inside another activity.

Comment: @Grishka: "And it's the only way to open an activity inside another activity" -- that was never a good idea, which is one of the reasons it is now deprecated.